# Avahi DNS working, other services not discovered

Tags: avahi

I have recently upgraded my motherboard on a 20.04 workstation and since then some avahi services do not seem to work.

`avahi-resolve-host` returns the correct IP addresses for hosts on my workstation. However my DAAP music library on my server does not show up in Rhythmbox. Using another machine on the same network, the music library is found. Similarly, a CUPS printer set up on the server is not found on the non-functioning workstation but is found on the other workstation.

`avahi-browse -art` returns no output. When the same command is run on the server, a long list of services is returned.

I'm at a loss to find where the problem lies.

As requested, below is the output of `service avahi-daemon status`

```
● avahi-daemon.service - Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/avahi-daemon.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-08-03 20:31:46 AWST; 1 weeks 5 days ago
TriggeredBy: ● avahi-daemon.socket
   Main PID: 1519 (avahi-daemon)
     Status: "avahi-daemon 0.7 starting up."
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 38408)
     Memory: 1.8M
     CGroup: /system.slice/avahi-daemon.service
             ├─1519 avahi-daemon: running [b5.local]
             └─1525 avahi-daemon: chroot helper

Aug 03 20:31:46 b5 systemd[1]: Starting Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack...
Aug 03 20:31:46 b5 avahi-daemon[1519]: Found user 'avahi' (UID 107) and group 'avahi' (GID 116).
Aug 03 20:31:46 b5 avahi-daemon[1519]: Successfully dropped root privileges.
Aug 03 20:31:46 b5 avahi-daemon[1519]: avahi-daemon 0.7 starting up.
Aug 03 20:31:46 b5 avahi-daemon[1519]: Successfully called chroot().
Aug 03 20:31:46 b5 avahi-daemon[1519]: Successfully dropped remaining capabilities.
Aug 03 20:31:46 b5 systemd[1]: Started Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
Aug 03 20:31:46 b5 avahi-daemon[1519]: No service file found in /etc/avahi/services.
Aug 03 20:31:46 b5 avahi-daemon[1519]: Network interface enumeration completed.
Aug 03 20:31:46 b5 avahi-daemon[1519]: Server startup complete. Host name is b5.local. Local service coo>
lines 1-22/22 (END)
```

Comment: Could you add the output of `service avahi-daemon status` to the question. Are the network interfaces of both machine on same sub-net?

Answer (score 0):

When changing your motherboard, maybe your NIC names changed, which may have affected your firewall rules? Check that port UDP/5353 and dst ip 224.0.0.251 are not being blocked on the workstation.

Comment: Port seems open. 
`netstat -tulpn | grep 5353
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           1519/avahi-daemon:  
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                1519/avahi-daemon:  
`